# maven repo for slf4j 1.7.x

Tags: maven, slf4j

I'm trying to use slf4j 1.7.0 (for vararg support), but maven errors out since it can't find it in repo1.maven.org. From what I can see, 1.6.6 seems to be the most up-to-date version.

Is there another public and trusted repo I can use to get it?

Also, 1.7.0 was released in Sept, so it's quite a few months. What is the general wait time for a release to make it to the repo1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see slf4j 1.7.x is available on central (eg: repo1.maven.org) under the group org.slf4j: http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1114494198

If you still can't obtain it, I suspect either:

- you had a bad maven artifact coordinate (old slf4j artifact is under 'slf4j' group rather than 'org.slf4j')
- your combined maven settings somehow mirror repo1.maven.org to a location that is not up to date (check with mvn:help effective-settings)
- or there's a problem with your maven caching mechanism (eg: your internal company maven repo caching did not sync / update properly)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer: it was the 3rd problem (internal company cache is out of date).
As a side note, why does this shows only 1.6.6 http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api? I spent quite a bit of time searching out for a place containing 1.7.x.

Comment: each maven repository is maintained by different parties, and they have different cache settings. Eg if it caches for too long it might just assume it always has the latest, and never checks updates from central. From my personal experience over time the the sync / update quality will degrade either because nobody in the company knows how to configure it / willing to volunteer :). A simple company internet proxy settings change might break the internal maven repo configuration. Have a look at nexus documentation for more info on administering a maven repo